# Is there any way to excute a command as a specific user in Python?

Tags: python, linux, shell, operating-system, command

As far as I kown, there are about 3 ways to excute a system command in Python:

1. `os.system(command) -> exit_status`
2. `os.popen(command [, mode='r' [, bufsize]]) -> pipe`
3. `commands.getoutput(command)-> string`

Now I need to control the excutor of a system command, beside the way like:

`os.system('su xxx;' + command)`

is there any other more elegant way to reach the same effect?

Comment: `os.popen` has been deprecated in favor of `subprocess`. [_citation_](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen)

Comment: What about `os.fork(); os.exec()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the things you've mentioned (which have been succeeded by the `subprocess` module by the way) are ways of spawning processes. You sound like you're looking for `setuid`. You can either call a function that will do that (e.g. `os.setuid`), or, as often is the case depending on what your script does, you can just run the entire script as the elevated user.

Answer (score 2):

Run a command as a different user using `subprocess` module (implementing [@Julian's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11662267/4279)). It is similar to [@tMC's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676563/4279) but at a higher level:

```
import os
import pwd
from subprocess import check_output as qx

def change_user(uid, gid=None):
    if gid is None:
        gid = uid
    def preexec_fn():
        os.setgid(gid)
        os.setgroups([gid])
        os.setuid(uid)
    return preexec_fn

print(qx(['id']))
print(qx(['id'], preexec_fn=change_user(pwd.getpwnam('nobody').pw_uid), env={}))
print(qx(['id']))
```

On old Python versions you might need to add `close_fds=True` in the subprocess calls to avoid fd leaks.

You could use `cwd` argument to specify a directory where to run the command e.g., a home directory of the user.

Populate `env` dictionary to set environment variables for the subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

While likely to 'low level' for most implementations, it might be educational to some to understand how this really happens in the higher level modules.

```
import os
import pwd

pout, pin = os.pipe()                                # Creates an anonymous pipe used to communicate with the child process

if not os.fork():                                    # The fork() syscall duplicated the process retuning 0 to the new child process.
    os.closerange(0, 2)                              # Closing stdin, stdout and stderr- they were inherited from the parent process
    os.dup2(pin, 1)                                  # Copy the input side of the IPC pipe to stdout (always fd 1)
    os.setuid(pwd.getpwnam('nobody').pw_uid)         # Change our user id to that of the user `nobody`.  Also see `setgid()`
    os.execl('/bin/whoami', 'whoami')                # Now that we've connected out stdout to the pipe connected to the parent process
                                                     #     and changed our user id to that of the user we want to run the command with
                                                     #     we can `exec()` the new process; replacing our currently running process, 
                                                     #     inheriting the env.
    os._exit(0)                                      # Since we called `exec` above, this is never eval'd, but is good form

os.wait()                                            # Back at the parent process- `wait()` will, well, wait until the child process exits.
os.close(pin)                                        # Close the input side of the pipe, the parent shouldn't write to. (bi-dirctional IPC
                                                     #     would require 2 pipes.  One in each direction
child_stdout_pipe = os.fdopen(pout, 'r')             # Open the output side of the IPC pipe
child_process_output = child_stdout_pipe.read()      # ...and read from the pipe.  This should include anything that came from the stdout of
                                                     #     the child process.  Since we closed the input side of the pipe, the `read()` 
                                                     #     will read an EOF after all the data in the pipe is returned.

print child_process_output                           # Win! (`write()`ing out the parent stdout want we found in the pipe from the child proc
```

Comment: the root group might remain without `setgid`, `setgroups` calls.

Comment: It does- I made mention of that in the comments